# Batch Validation of metacafe, dailymotion and youtube videos

Tags: php, youtube

I'm creating a video database and want to remove all the videos which are deleted from metacafe, dailymotion and youtube.

Is there a way we can identify all the deleted videos in batch mode.

Comment: Can you please post some code? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. YouTube offers an [API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html), which you can use to extract this information.

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/#{video_id}
```

You can use the above API URL to get the information about the video. To check if it is deleted, you can inspect the value of [`yt:state`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?csw=1#youtube_data_api_tag_yt%3astate) tag.

> The `<yt:state>` tag contains information that describes the status of a video that cannot be played. Video entries that contain a `<yt:state>` tag are not playable. The name and reasonCode attributes and the tag value provide insight into the reason why the video is not playable.

Create a script that inspects the tag value for a given video, and run all your videos through this script.

Comment: how do you inspect the state tag ?

Comment: @jesses.co.tt: Parse the XML using SimpleXML and get the value.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm using the API and getting JSON responses, and I don't see this. Where/how do i get XML ?